# C++ linking error CVT1100: duplicate resource

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fatal-error

```
1>CVTRES : fatal error CVT1100: duplicate resource.  type:TYPELIB, name:1, language:0x0409 
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

I'm trying to convert an existing C++ project from 32-bit to 64-bit and from VS6 to VS2008. Can anyone tell me why this error is occurring and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error message, with the `CVT1100` ... `type:TYPELIB`, but in my case I included two resource files (Uniting two DLLs into one - done years ago) - [Microsoft suggested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/cvtres-fatal-error-cvt1100?view=vs-2019) to give the resource a different number. But they already had a different number.

MyProjectNameRes.rc:

```
:
:
3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "1 TYPELIB ""MyProjectNameRes.tlb""\r\n"
    "\0"
END
:
:
1 TYPELIB "MyProjectNameRes.tlb"
:
```

MyProjectName.rc

```
:
3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "2 TYPELIB ""MyProjectName.tlb""\r\n"
    "#include ""MyProjectNameRes\\MyProjectNameRes.rc"" // For Res dll union\r\n"
resources\r\n"
END
:
:
2 TYPELIB "MyProjectName.tlb"
#include "MyProjectNameRes\MyProjectNameRes.rc" // For Res dll union
:
```

It turns out that the "1" is reserved by the including resource file (I couldn't put my finger on the exact reason), therefore I replace the "1" to "3" in the included resource.

In MyProjectNameRes.rc:

- `"1 TYPELIB ""MyProjectNameRes.tlb""\r\n"` -> `"3 TYPELIB ""MyProjectNameRes.tlb""\r\n"`
- `1 TYPELIB "MyProjectNameRes.tlb"` -> `3 TYPELIB "MyProjectNameRes.tlb"`

*Note that I encountered this issue, after moving to visual studio 2017, and fixing it.

It was not possible to open the resource file with the following message:
[image]

> A resource in this file uses an unknown language: Neutral (Default) (unknown sub-lang: 0x3)
> Unable to open this file.

If I remember correctly: [I had to leave only one language in my resource files.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401694/10571377) and [convert the file to UTF-16.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455968/10571377)