# VS2019: How to resolve the "unknown sub-lang: 0x8" message in Resource View?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2019

I have recently started using Visual Studio 2019 for my C++11 project. VS2019 converted the project and it compiles into an executable. But I can't open my resource (.rc) file in the Resource Viewer. It gives me this warning:

> A resource in this file uses an unknown language: Neutral (Default)
>   (unknown sub-lang: 0x8). Unable to open this file.

[image]

I tried trimming the resource file to bare necessity but that did not work.

The strange thing is that it also happens with Scribble, Microsofts example project. I downloaded it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/walkthrough-updating-the-mfc-scribble-application-part-1?view=vs-2019 using the [Scribble 1.0 MFC sample] link under the Prerequisites header.

When the solution is opened in VS2019, it is converted, it compiles, but I can't open the accompanying resource file to look at the Dialogs.

Any help is appreciated!

Best regards,
Keun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution helped for me:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/96766/view.html

When you have multiple language settings in your Windows, remove all but one. I had to leave the English (US) option. Then the resource opens again without problems.
Hope this helps someone (or myself in the future as this is the second time I spend an hour to search for a solution).

Comment: And between explicit English (LANG_ENGLISH) and Default (LANG_NEUTRAL) which seems to exist even if you don't choose it. What is the best to store English?

Comment: Good question. As I see it, you place a string as Neutral when it is the same for multiple/all languages ... e.g. the name of the company or application. And language specific strings in their LANG_ section. If you really only have one language then there is no big difference I guess, but would suggest to use LANG_ENGLISH (that is: the ID for your language) for future extensibility.
More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-resource-management

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not related to the language setting, but the RC file is stored incorrectly. My file was in ANSI format. As soon as I opened the file with Windows Notepad and saved it as Unicode, I was able to open and edit the resource project in the studio again. (0xFF 0xFE was missing)

Answer (score 2):

Posting my solution for those that encounter similar issues.

I found that the malfunctioning rc files had ANSI encoding. Converting them to UTF-8 did the trick. You can easily do that using Notepad++ via the [Encoding] menu option, select [Convert to UTF-8].

What I don't understand is why VS doesn't fix this itself when converting a project.

Comment: Although I found this solution in another forum also, it did not help with me.

Comment: @msof Actually I did not convert it to UTF-8, I converted it to UNICODE (in note pad - I assume this is UTF-16) - And it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me, was to replace this:

> LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
>
> #pragma code_page(1252)

(which specifies language English, US with ANSI Latin 1; Western European (Windows) encoding)

By this :

> LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
>
> #pragma code_page(65001)

(which specifies Language neutral with UTF-8 encoding)

Once I'd made that change (making sure the .rc file was UTF-8 encoded), Visual Studio no longer complained.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers
and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-makelangid#remarks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the language actually did not matter in my case, I just converted it to UNICODE (in Microsoft Notepad - I assume this is UTF-16) - And it did the trick.

Note that there is an answer here, [regarding UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455968/10571377), which did not work for me.

Comment: This worked for me too. Saved it to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that worked for me.

1. Open the *.rc file in the 'Code View' in Visual Studio.
2. Search for the following section:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_NEUSD)
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_SYS_DEFAULT
#pragma code_page(1252)
...
```

3. Comment the complete `#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_NEUSD)` block and save the file.
4. Open the file in the 'Resource View'. Close it. (Maybe you have to change and save something here)
5. Reopen the *.rc file via the 'Code View' in Visual Studio. Uncomment the previously commented section and save the file.

After this steps the problem was solved. I don't know which of the steps solved the problem but in the end this was my way to solve the issue.

My solution was inspired by the following solution: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/40860/Resource-file-opening-problem