# VS2019 : resource file error: Neutral (Default) (unknown sub-lang: 0x8)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/@malortie/win32-app-load-apply-resources-to-window-c-cpp-visual-studio-du107jdb4) to get started with win32api GUI programming. My VS2019 is completely standard but when i try to add a resource file i get the error:

```
A resource in this file uses an unknown language: Neutral (Default) (unknown sub-lang: 0x8). Unable to open this file.
```

I found something similar posted before, but the suggested fixes didnt work for me. i only have one language installed on my W10 machine. Any idea what could be wrong with my settings?

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//

#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE 9, 1

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE  
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE  
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Comment: According to the tutorial, I have tried to reproduce the issue. However, the error didn’t occur.If you could offer your language setting and other relevant code, We will provide you with better help.  

Also, I find [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441565/vs2019-how-to-resolve-the-unknown-sub-lang-0x8-message-in-resource-view) which may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Before posting my question i tried the solutions in that tread (file format, removing, additional language packs) but still i have the error. The error also arises when i take an empty project and try to add a resource file.

Please see in this screenshot my language setting
https://i.postimg.cc/0j4V1cbw/image.png

Comment: This screenshot shows that your `Preferred languages` is `English(Netherlands)`. I suggest that you could set `Windows display language` to `English (United States)`. You could refer to the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124475/can-not-open-resource-file-in-resource-view.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Jeaninez setting my Window display language to `English (United States)` fixed the problem. This seems to align with the default settings in Visual Studio 2019.